# Forget doesn't work

Tags: collections, laravel

If I try to remove an item from this collection

```
$examples = Example::where('example', '=', $data['example'])->get();
```

by doing

```
$examples->forget(20);
```

it doesn't remove the item from the collection, I still get back all the items that were in there originally. I have read the Laravel documentation and the api docs. And it should work (I think) but it doesn't.

Could someone point me out what I am doing wrong here?

This still returns an object.

```
$examples->forget(49);
return $examples->find(49);
```

P.S. Ever other method like push or get works.

Thanks alot!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You did a small mistake, actually you didn't notice that. I did myself :).

`Forget` uses the `array key` to delete an object item from a collection.

```
Array(0 => 'abc'
 1 => 'bcd'
 49 => 'aaa'
)

$examples->forget(49);
                  ^^ array key 49
```

Whereas, `find` uses the `id` to find an object from a collection

```
table: examples

id example
1   abc
49  bce

$examples->find(49);
                ^^ `example id`
```

Comment: Thanks that was the problem indeed. Is there any way to easily "forget" by id of an object?

Comment: You can do `->reject('foo')` in Laravel 7 - even though the docs suggest otherwise. See Ali Baker's answer and my comment.

Answer (score 3):

According to the documentation it says that `forget()` works by key. The word "*key*" is ambiguous because what they mean to say is array key also known as "*index*" and not model key which is the id.

However, in the other methods such as `find()` or `contains()` they use the word "*key*" to mean model key so you can see the confusion.

When you look at the source you can see that the `forget()` method is found in the `Illuminate\Support\Collection` class and not in `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection`.

My theory is that the support class is supposed to be more generic so it doesn't consider the model keys, but really I don't know.

Answer (score 2):

I just wanted to add on to the Anam's answer. Once you have a collection you can then loop through it like this to delete by ID

```
function forgetById($collection,$id){
    foreach($collection as $key => $item){
        if($item->id == $id){
            $collection->forget($key);
            break;
        }
    }
    return $collection;
}

$examples = Example::where('example', '=', $data['example'])->get();

$examples = forgetById($examples,20);
```

Answer (score 2):

you could do

```
$examples->reject(20);
```

Like most other collection methods, reject returns a new collection instance; it does not modify the collection it is called on.

Comment: I was about to mark this down, because the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/collections#method-reject) strongly implies you need a callback, but in fact you can just supply an item name and it will remove it (from the new instance). Callbacks do work as well of course. Things that don't: forget(), except().  Tested with Laravel 7.27.

Comment: Yh I guess this was a long time ago well before v7.27