# Laravel: how to remove item from Collection by id

Tags: php, laravel

I want to remove the admin user from my collection. I know its the primary key in the table (id) is 1. But when I use `forget(1)` it deletes the array element in the collection starting from 0. How do I remove the item from the collection by the id?

```
    // Grab all the users
    $users = User::all(); //$this->user;  use to return array not Laravel Object
    if($users->find(1)->hasRole('admin'))
        $users->forget(0);
```

Comment: you mean,you don't want to delete that from database?just from $users collection?

Comment: yes. i don't want to display the admin user in the list of users on my view.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Forget doesn't work](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20735181/forget-doesnt-work)

Comment: I tried pull($key) as well and same problem. $key is definitely not the primary key or $id. It seems that $key is the array index starting at 0 instead.

Comment: I replaced  `$users->find(1)` with `$users[0]` to check the element instead of the id

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Instead of trying to delete an item from the collection, it would be better to never select it in the first place.

You could add a constraint to your DB query like this:

```
$users = User::where('role', '!=', 'admin')->get();
```

(It could be slightly different depending on how roles are defined in your schema).

If you are using a more complex schema with a separate `roles` table and `user_role` table, you can query like this:

```
$users = User::whereHas('roles', function($q){
    $q->where('role', '!=', 'admin');
})->get();
```

It's a bad idea to rely on the admin user always being the first item in the collection. What if later you want to have multiple admin users, or to sort the user list by registration date? If you really want to remove admin from the collection, Eloquent has built-in filtering functionality:

```
$usersWithoutAdmins = $users->filter(function($user)
{
    return !$user->hasRole('admin');
});
```

Comment: Very nice answer. I am using Confide/Entrust which would correspond to your 2nd solution except it uses the column `name` instead of `roles`. The solution does not select users that have no role assigned... I will need to enforce assigning roles to all users which I probably should do anyhow...so overkill for what I needed but oh well. Not going to take me that long to do I hope.

Comment: I ran into much difficulty with Confide/Entrust trying to save relation for the role...please see [laravel-how-to-query-to-get-all-records-except-where-relation-has-name-column]
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28095206/laravel-how-to-query-to-get-all-records-except-where-relation-has-name-column
if you know how to do your 2nd query you showed me to get the users that have no roles as well.

Comment: This is not an answer to the actual question.

Answer (score 26):

As such **bencohenbaritone**'s answer is better way to resolve this problem, I have to add that Laravel Eloquent Collection has method `except()`, which can remove Eloquent objects from the collection by *primary key* instead of `forget()`. The latter one removes by collection index key (like `array[i]`) and not by primary key.

So you can write something like (sorry about the bad example, my own use case is too different to be useful for others):

```
$admin_user_id = 20;
$users = User::all();
$users_without_admin = $users->except($admin_user_id);
```

Comment: This helped me, because I have a situation that I can't properly do with a database-only query and this was just the ticket!