# Laravel: how to query to get all records except where relation has name column = admin

Tags: laravel

I have this query

```
$users = User::whereHas('roles', function($q){
    $q->where('name', '!=', 'admin');
})->get();
```

but I want to get all users including the ones that have no roles associated. Is there a way to query this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to get the users where the number of roles matching 'admin' is less than one:

```
$users = User::whereHas('roles', function($q){
    $q->where('name', 'admin');
}, '<', 1)->get();
```

[`whereHasNot` is coming, but not in a release yet](https://github.com/laravel/framework/pull/6686).

Comment: Amazing, thanks so much! Can you explain the semantic meaning of `< 1`? How does `< 1`  translate to whereHasNot? Is it based on SQL and are there other switches?

Comment: @Phil The various `has` functions allow an operator and count, so you could do stuff like fetch only blog posts with 10+ comments. In this case, we're fetching users with 0 roles matching the name 'admin'.

Comment: Ahhh thanks! Now I see what is going on with the has, hasNot, whereHas, and upcoming whereHasNot functions!